# Why are my values not being kept between instances of a type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the class:

```
public class pro {
    private string url = string.Empty;
    public string GetURL() { return url; }
    public void SetURL(string value) { url = value; }
}
```

In this line I'm getting value:

```
string url = li1.Value;  

pro itm = new pro();  // I have create Proprtie so I'm calling that

itm.SetURL(url); // here I'm setting value
```

Then later:

```
pro itm = new pro(); //properties object I have created

string url = itm.GetURL(); // I'm not getting value which I have set in first
```

class.

I have create Proprties also; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried to make sense of the question body (although it is still a bit unclear) - but I can't make any sense of the title; can you please try to rephease?

Comment: Can you show us the `pro` class?

Comment: You don't use the same instance. You create a new  instance of `pro` in the second class.

Comment: basically i have call String variable from one class to another class using set and get method means what ever string value incoming in my first one class same string value shud come in second class..

Comment: @Anil why should it? that makes no sense. That is like saying "If I rename a customer to Fred, every customer is now called Fred"

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication8
{
  

    public class pro
    {
        private string url = string.Empty;

        public string GetURL()
        {
            return url;
        }

        public void SetURL(string value)
        {
            url = value;
        }

    }
}

Comment: @Anil I've merged that into the question: you should see an "edit" button - you can use that to edit the question!

Answer (score 3):

Every class instance (i.e. every `new pro()`) has different instance values; it is perfectly expected that if you have 2 different instances, then they will not share a `URL`, for example. If you want to share this, you should make the **same** `pro` instance available to both places, by passing the `pro` around.

Incidentally, `GetURL()` / `SetURL()` is not idiomatic C# - it would be more common to have a *property*, i.e.

```
public string Url {get;set;}
```

which you would then access as:

```
YourType item = new YourType();
item.Url = "http://foo.com/bar/";
// ... 
string url = item.Url;
```

---

From the comments, it *sounds* like you are talking about `static` data; I should emphasise that using `static` for this is not usually a good idea, and can lead to lots of problems with testing, multi-tenancy, threading, etc; but: the following works **without any** instances:

```
public class Properties {
    public static string Url {get;set;}
}
...
Properties.Url = "http://foo.com/bar/";
...
string url = Properties.Url;
```

note: no instances at all.

However, it is almost always preferable to simply keep an *instance* available, and use instance properties against that common instance.

Answer (score 3):

May be I understood your problem :

The thing is that in **second** you create a **new**  instance of `pro` class. If you want to acess the string value set in **first** class, you should use that first `pro` object.

If it's not your problem, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have some class like application properties you can use static class.

```
public static class pro
{
  public static string Url {get; set;}
}
```

and use it like `pro.Url = "aa"`;