# How to use string value from one class to another class using Properties

Tags: c#

I have the class:

```
   public class pro {

         private string url = string.Empty;

         public string GetURL() { return url; }              

         public void SetURL(string value) { url = value; }
   }
```

In this line I'm getting value:

```
    string url = li1.Value;          
    pro itm = new pro();  // I have create Proprtie so I'm calling that   
    itm.SetURL(url); // here I'm setting value
```

Then later:

```
     pro itm = new pro(); //properties object I have created
     string url = itm.GetURL(); // I'm not getting value which I have set in first class.
```

I have create Properties also; what am I doing wrong?

Tell me how to get my String value of first class to second class using Properties. Tell me the code for that I am trying that but not able to do that.

Comment: "What am doing wrong" - naming class "pro" and variable "itm" for code that you want other people to read is definitly one of the things.

Comment: When you say "then later", do you mean that code is running in a different method or on a different page?

Comment: You've asked the exact same question here and haven't accepted an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715520/why-are-my-values-not-being-kept-between-instances-of-a-type

Answer (score 2):

If the code is as you describe it, then you must use the same `itm` that you performed the `SetURL` on. It looks like you are instantiating a new `pro`, which will not be the same one that you had run the `SetURL` on, so it will be Empty (that is the default here).

However, you should just use .NET properties instead of GetURL and SetURL.

```
public class pro
{
    public string Url {get;set;}
}
```

You can also, then use object initializers (this is only open to you if you are using one of the more current versions of .NET, though)

```
pro itm = new pro{Url=li1.Value};
```

And, finally, to access the value:

```
itm.Url;
```

Now, you could make the class and its methods static, so that every object that calls it will see the same last value, also. IF, that is what you are really looking for

Comment: But pro itm = new pro(); means that "itm" is being declared again, which means that it will throw a compile error. So, if the code is running, he's just using 2 different objects.

Comment: Yes, that is a distinct possibility. I am just trying to give as much as I can given the state of the question...in case it was mistyped in some way

Comment: how to call this value in second class plz send me that code for that

Comment: read my answer. It doesn't need to be a class to be honest, at least with whatever info you've provided

Comment: I think you need to try to explain your question a little better. Are you saying that the itm being set is happening in a different class/method than where it is being read? If that is the case, then you need to pass the object being set into the other class/method. If that does not work for you, then you need to provide more code

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you should be passing the object around instead of re-creating the object. You're using 2 different objects

To be honest it doesn't need to be a class, all its doing is setting and getting a string property, why don't you just make it a string property in the class that is using it?

Like this:

```
private string ProUrl {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

2nd time you are creating new instance of  pro and then without setting the value of 
pro.url  for the second instance you are trying to get the value. so it obviously  takes default value.

```
string url = li1.Value;  
pro itm = new pro();  // I have created a Proprty so I'm calling that
itm.SetURL(url); // here I'm setting value
```

print `itm.GetURL()` now . should be able to see the value being set.

Or if you requirement is to retain the single copy of variable throughout then use [static variables](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=static%20variables%20%2b%20msdn&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=1dNiT-nvDoSf0QWimdCiCA&usg=AFQjCNEDY09w-cGJgpl5oDZM_xmon8zPOw)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean set filed url to static ?

```
public class pro 
{
    static private string url = string.Empty;

    public string GetURL() { return url; }

    public void SetURL(string value) { url = value; }
}
```

Comment: NO i just want call one String vriable value from One class to another class using Proprties in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

You just need to this to get above functionality:

```
    public class Pro
    {
        // Auto-Impl Properties for trivial get and set
        public String Url { get; set; }
    }

    //Here accessing the property of Url
     Pro proUrl = new Pro();// // Intialize a new object.
     proUrl.Url = "www.google.com";//Setting the value

     Console.WriteLine("The url is {0}",proUrl.Url);
```